# Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server on MacOS MAMP Pro

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, mamp, mamp-pro

anyone please can help me? I'am new in developing php appliacations on mac (till now I developed on windows) and I need help with installing ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server for MAMP Pro.
I installed the driver according to the instructions on https://github.com/Braineee/microsoft-driver-on-mamp-for-mac/blob/master/README.md  and the error is that the driver was not found.

Here are screenshot from phpinfo:
[phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgsXM.png)
[phpinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvHsy.png)

Extension in MAMP Pro are added:
[MAMP Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUyEX.png)

Files are copied into MAMP:
[MAMP Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUeZl.png)

PHP version: 8.1.13

How I'am connecting to MSSQL Server:

```
private const SQLdriver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server';
private const SQLserver = '192.168.1.12';
private const SQLport = 1433;
private const SQLDBName = '?';
private const SQLusername = '?';
private const SQLpassword = '?';
private const SQLparameters = 'TDS_Version=8.0;ClientCharset=UTF-8;';
private const SQLDriverOptions = [PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL];

$dsn = 'DRIVER=' . self::SQLdriver . ';' . 'SERVER=' . self::SQLserver . ';' . (empty(self::SQLport) ? '' : 'PORT=' . self::SQLport . ';') . 'DATABASE=' . ($this->dbType === Marfos::DB_TYPE_MAIN ? self::SQLDBName : self::SQLDBNameTest) . ';' . self::SQLparameters;
$this->pdo = new PDO("odbc:" . $dsn . "", self::SQLusername, self::SQLpassword);
$this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR, PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL);
```

The connection on windows WAMP server is good. On mac I tried everything, but the driver was not found.

Thank you very much for your answers.

I searched all webs and tried everyrthing to install the ODBC Driver a I expect help.

Answer (score 0):

Your phpinfo() shows that you have the [PDO_SQLSRV](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) extension installed. You don't use it through ODBC but via a specific [DSN](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php), e.g.:

```php
$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=testdb", "UserName", "Password");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but same problem: could not find driver. PDO is also installed